# HTML <select> control disabled in Android WebView (in emulator)

Tags: android, android-emulator, webview, html-select

I have a very simple Android app that's just a WebView.  Everything works fine (complex Javascript etc.).  However, all of the HTML `select` controls seem to be disabled.  They display with default values, but nothing happens when I click on them, and they don't get the orange highlight when I arrow through the controls.

Other inputs (text, radios, submit) work fine, so I don't think it's a focus issue.

Configuration:

- Eclipse IDE
- SDK Version 8 (2.2)
- Testing in the Emulator

Comment: I noticed a similar problem, when the select is clicked, it immediately crashes the program, with E/AndroidRuntime(24999): FATAL EXCEPTION: WebViewCoreThread
E/AndroidRuntime(24999): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
E/AndroidRuntime(24999):  at android.webkit.WebView$InvokeListBox.<init>(WebView.java:7001)

Comment: Apparently if you have <hr> in the <select> it will cause force close, even in the standard browser.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find any solution?

Comment: @FadyEmad See possible answers below.  I changed frameworks for the mobile app, so this wasn't an issue any more.  FYO, I'm using Framework7: https://framework7.io/ which has been great.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. My problem was fixed by changing `overflow:hidden` to `overflow:visible` on a containing element.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

In my case I had elements on the page that had the style `position:fixed;`

Although the bounding boxes of the select element and the fixed positioned elements did NOT overlap, I wasn't able to open the select dialog.

By removing a couple of fixed positioned elements I got it to work. Seems to be a bug in webview.

Comment: interesting.  header is position:static, so that's a likely candidate. i'll poke around and see what happens. thanks mandro.

Answer (score 0):

Same Problem, fixed it by setting `position:relative` on the li's containing the select fields

Answer (score 0):

2 years after the fact, but in case someone pulls this up again:

If it's android 2.3, put   in every empty child element of a fixed position parent. I found that this fixed the problem for me.