# set a new context to WebView

Tags: android, webview, android-context

Is there any way to change the context of WebView?
I mean, when I extend the WebView class I call the super constructor with a context (in my example an activity). Later on, this activity is no longer exists and we move to other activity.

The problem is the WebView is still alive and has a reference to this context.
I can't create my WebView any time because the initialisation is long.
I tried to call the super class with getApplicationContext() but I found that this also problematic for displaying videos.

What can I do in order to set the WebView's context without create a new one.

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/06/context/ Maybe this will help you understand what is the best context for your needs

Answer (score 2):

To pass new context to webview you can create a method to initialize webview, passing an argument of Context like shown below:

```
public static Webview initializeWebView(Context context)
{

  myWebView = new WebView();
  return myWebView;

}
```

And after this you can call this method whereever you want and whenever you want. You can call this as shown below:

```
myWebView = initializeWebView(YourActivityName.this);
//this way whatever Context you will pass your webview will be initialized that way
//for example you can also pass getApplicationContext() as an Argument
myWebView = initializeWebView(getApplicationContext());
//or
myWebView = initializeWebView(customContext);
```

this customContext can be any context that is inherited from other context that you wanted to use.

Comment: This should be the solution (and thanks for the excellent answer).

Comment: @RickardElimää :-)

Comment: @ManishSharma can you please explain: You are passing a context, that you don't use. Thatswhy you can pass whatever context you want. Why not just call `WebView()` directly?