# Why does Android OS 8 WebVew with HTML select tag crash the app

Tags: android, android-webview, android-8.0-oreo

I've got a hybrid Cordova Android app, and the app crashes when user tap on a drop-down box in my `WebView` running on Android OS 8. I've created a simple page with a `<select>` tag and the issue is reproducible. I've got a workaround which is to do my own pop up alert to select, but just wondering if this is happening to anyone else and whether this is an OS8 `WebView` bug.

Below is a simple page with `<select>` tag

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select

Below is my crash log

```
11:04:58.643 3208-3208/com.****.****E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.****.****, PID: 3208 android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:195)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2133)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1142)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:421)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:416)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:407)
    at org.chromium.content.browser.input.SelectPopupAdapter.getView(SelectPopupAdapter.java:53)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2372)
    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1408)
    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1315)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21998)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21998)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21998)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21998)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21998)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21998)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:721)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21998)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2410)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1471)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1751)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1386)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6733)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

My issue is not the same as this

[Trying to open SELECT tag in Android WebView crashes the application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9213170/trying-to-open-select-tag-in-android-webview-crashes-the-application)

UPDATE on 9th Jan 2018:
I haven't got a solution yet, my temporary workaround is remove the  tag and just use an input. When user select this element, we pass the event to native code to pop up a dialog for selection and update the input once user made a selection.

UPDATE on 23rd March 2018:
After some more investigation, I noticed that it only crashes if the WebView is in a Fragment, but not in an Activity.

I found below comments from this post:

[Trying to open SELECT tag in Android WebView crashes the application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9213170/trying-to-open-select-tag-in-android-webview-crashes-the-application)

"When a SELECT tag is clicked, Android internally displays its options using a native AlertDialog.
Webview must be created with an Activity context because AlertDialog instance needs an Activity context."

I believe this is a bug in Android, probably not handling Context properly for Fragment.

**UPDATE 17th of April 2018:**

As kenyee pointed out, from here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/77246450, Google says

> You mustn't subclass the resources object - this was never supported and was only possible by accident (which is why it's now marked deprecated). The framework needs to know about all the resources objects so that it can update them when webview is loaded (since webview adds additional paths to the asset manager).

**Edit 29th November 2018**
Seems this issue has bothered a lot of people.

- The solution I've tried and tested to work is to not subclassing the Resource.
- Updating compile sdk and supported library version worked for some people.
- Adding a wrapper class to Resource may work, I've tried this approach during my initial investigation, it solved the Select crashing issue, still crashes when you click and hold on a text view to pop up the "COPY", "PASTE" options.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on a Google Pixel running Android 8.0.0. Tapping the drop-down box pops up a dialog as expected. My `WebView` configuration is minimal, just `setJavaScriptEnabled(true)`. FWIW, this problem [seems to have been reported earlier this year for Android 7.0](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37137929), but nobody provided a reproducible test case, so the issue went nowhere.

Comment: Any news on this?

Comment: Can I know how you fix this issue? I am also getting the same issue in my app in Google Pixel. But its working fine in pixel browser and also in another dummy app I created.

Comment: Hello @Dennis Hui . Is that oage working fine in the Phones Browser?

Comment: Hello. Why are you not responding

Comment: can you reduce it to straight java?  Does it fail in other OS's (ex: simulator)?

Comment: We are facing the same issue. Any updates on this?

Comment: I only saw it on my device, others didn't. Then I thought let's try the release version too (like the others were using) and there it wasn't visible!

Comment: @CommonsWare Please see my updates. It only happens when a WebView is inside fragment, not in Activity.

Comment: @TominB Sorry missed your question before, yes, it's working fine in Phone Browser, it only happens in WebView inside Fragment.

Comment: @SwapnilSonar Please see my updates.

Comment: It's not limited to fragment, happening in Activity also

Comment: @VarunAjayGupta Have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this bug:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/77246450

Don't subclass resources...won't be fixed apparently.

Answer (score 3):

I have same issue on Android 8.0 .
finally i solve it.
Try to update your compileSdkVersion to 26,
and update your com.android.support:appcompat-v7 to 26.

Comment: Don't add comments here.

Comment: upgrading compileSdkVersion and all support library versions solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is still having this issue, I found that it wasn't even my code that was subclassing the Resources class but rather the Google support library version that I was using. Updated the support library version and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

In AndroidX land (limited to a minimum compileSDKVersion 28), I was also getting this issue on a Marshmallow emulator with a popup spinner. I don't go anywhere near Resources so this is still a platform issue with one of the support libs.

I managed to get it working - not by moving the webview to an Activity (although I did try that, it was unnecessary), - but by adding it programmatically with a wrapped context and a standard AppCompat theme:

```
val webView = WebView(ContextThemeWrapper(activity, R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light))
binding.webViewContainer.addView(webView)
```

I don't understand wtf is going on here but right now it works. Good luck people!

**EDIT**
I have looked into this a lot more and found the dependency which is causing issues for me. A particular version of the material components library is actually inducing this in webviews (1.1.0-alpha06 to be precise). [I have asked a question on it here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/134610936), with a sample project.

Comment: @Deniel This solution stop crashing app but dialog is not open when i click on select tag, long press is working fine , any suggestion why dialog is not opening?

Answer (score 2):

Actually found a workaround for this a little while ago that allowed us to continue subclassing `Resources` and not crash our WebViews. The caveat is we can't let our WebView see or interact with our resources subclass AND we must create the WebView programmaticaly. The first step is exposing method in the Resources subclass to pull the original resources back out.

Lets say our resources subclass is called `CustomResourcesWrapper` and our `ContextWrapper` subclass is called `CustomContextWrapper`.

First we update the `CustomResourcesWrapper` so we can access the original `Resources` object

```
public class CustomResourcesWrapper {

    public static Resources findOriginalResources(Context context) {
        if (context.getResources() instanceof CustomResourcesWrapper) {
            return ((CustomResourcesWrapper) context.getResources()).getOriginalResources();
        }
        if (context instanceof ContextWrapper) {
            return findOriginalResources(((ContextWrapper) context).getBaseContext());
        }
        return context.getResources();
    }

    private Resources getOriginalResources() {
        return originalResources;
    }
}
```

We're also assuming the `CustomContextWrapper` looks something like this...

```
public class CustomContextWrapper extends ContextWrapper {

    private final Resources wrappedResources;

    public CustomContextWrapper(Context base, Resources resources) {
        super(base);
        this.wrappedResources = resources;
    }

    @Override
    public Resources getResources() {
        return wrappedResources;
    }
}
```

Then we create a static helper method to "unwrap" our custom resources and hide them

```
// the method name is a bit of a misnomer, 
// we're actually unwrapping, then re-wrapping
public static Context unwrapCustomContext(Context wrapped) {
    Resources originalResources = CustomResourcesWrapper.findOriginalResources(wrapped);
    Context customUnwrappedContext = new CustomContextWrapper(wrapped, originalResources);
    return new ContextThemeWrapper(customUnwrappedContext, android.support.v7.appcompat.R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light);
}
```

When it comes time to create a WebView, do it ensure the `Context` we pass to it runs through the above method i.e. `WebView webView = new WebView(unwrapCustomContext(context))`. I'm not 100% sure why, but the `ContextThemeWrapper` is a required part of this hack.

Comment: I think I tried this approach and it worked for the SELECT tag, but it still crashed when you click and hold on a text view to pop up the COPY PASTE options.

Comment: hmm, doesn't seem to be a problem in our implementation (just did a quick test and was able to copy some text just fine)

Answer (score 1):

I digged into crash logs. Though this answer does not solve your problem, you might get some useful insights

- Webiview uses [this layout file **select_dialog_singlechoice.xml**](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/select_dialog_singlechoice.xml)  for inflating Spinner item using [ArrayAdaper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)
- You are getting Resource not found Exception [from here](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/d18ed49f9dba09b85782c83999a9103dec015bf2/core/java/android/content/res/ResourcesImpl.java#L206)
- It means that Your Webview is not able to locate this resource file when you click on select tag

I am not sure why it's happening on Android 8.0,i was not able to reproduce this on Android 8.0 emulator though

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation, I've isolated the issue to WebView inside Fragment on OS8 only. My workaround is to use Activity instead of Fragment for that particular flow. It seems to me an Android defect in Fragment.

Comment: [Here is a sample app](https://commonsware.com/misc/WebViewFragment-20180323.zip) showing that `WebView` works fine in a `Fragment` when displaying the Web page at the URL from your question. Tested on Android 8.1 (Nexus 5X).

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the sample application. You are right, fragment with WebView wasn't the reason for the crash. It turned out it's caused by overriding the getRecource() function in Activity. I've slightly modified your project and made it crash. Uploaded [here](https://github.com/dennishui/MyApplication)

Comment: Then perhaps do not override `getResource()`. I would consider that to be a fairly significant code smell in its own right.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you use custom `ContextWrapper` in your `Activity` class. In my case, I override `attachBaseContext` method. Check this method and use `super.attachBaseContext(newBase)`.

Answer (score -3):

Its look like you are setting Integer value to the Textview. try using `String.valueOf(value)` to set value in Textview.

Comment: The question is about a Select element in a WebView.