# Android O Webview crash with DexGuard

Tags: android, webview, android-8.0-oreo, dexguard

This crash has only been reproducible in Android 8/8.1 for me. This also only happens in obfuscated builds, unobfuscated builds are not affected. I have tried adding keep rules for the entire codebase and all dependencies and it does not fix the crash, but `-dontobfuscate` does.

On first launch, the app works fine and when you click a spinner, it pops up the `SelectPopupAdapter` dialog. On second launch, the same spinner will crash the app if selected. Clearing the app data makes the spinner work again.

The class is a fairly simple webview:

```
public class WebViewActivity {

@BindView(R.id.web_view)
WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    setupWebSettings();

    webView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebview());
    webView.postUrl(url, postData.getBytes());
    webView.setOnKeyListener((v, keyCode, event) -> {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            WebView webView = (WebView) v;
            switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                        webView.goBack();
                        return true;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        return false;
    });
}

private void setupWebSettings() {
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
}

@Override
public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment fragment) {
    fragment.dismiss();
    finish();
}

@Override
public void finish() {
    setResult(RESULT_OK);
    super.finish();
}

private class CustomWebview extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        //logging
    }
}
}
```

Here is the crash log:

```
Crashed: main: 0 0 0x0000000000000000
   at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:195)
   at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2133)
   at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1142)
   at com.guardsquare.dexguard.CV.getLayout(Unknown Source:94)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:421)
   at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:416)
   at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:407)
   at org.chromium.content.browser.input.SelectPopupAdapter.getView(SelectPopupAdapter.java:13)
   at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2372)
   at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1408)
   at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1315)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21998)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21998)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21998)
   at com.android.internal.widget.AlertDialogLayout.tryOnMeasure(AlertDialogLayout.java:144)
   at com.android.internal.widget.AlertDialogLayout.onMeasure(AlertDialogLayout.java:69)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21998)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21998)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21998)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
   at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:721)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21998)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2410)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1471)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1751)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1386)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6733)
   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

--

Fatal Exception: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
   at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:195)
   at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2133)
   at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1142)
   at com.guardsquare.dexguard.CV.getLayout(Unknown Source:94)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:421)
   at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:416)
   at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:407)
   at org.chromium.content.browser.input.SelectPopupAdapter.getView(SelectPopupAdapter.java:13)
   at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2372)
   at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1408)
   at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1315)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21998)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21998)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21998)
   at com.android.internal.widget.AlertDialogLayout.tryOnMeasure(AlertDialogLayout.java:144)
   at com.android.internal.widget.AlertDialogLayout.onMeasure(AlertDialogLayout.java:69)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21998)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21998)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21998)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
   at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:721)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21998)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2410)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1471)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1751)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1386)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6733)
   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: I see the same issue on my webviews, also only for Android O, did you find anything?

Comment: BTW, this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46208138/why-does-android-os-8-webvew-with-html-select-tag-crash-the-app

Comment: Did you guys fixed this issue? I am also getting the same issue