# Why clicking select tag in web content causes a crash?

Tags: android, webview

I have a simple `WebView` where JavaScript is enabled and `WebChromeClient` is used. A web content that I am loading has a `select` tag. When I click on it, the app crashes with following snippet of error:

```
 android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1351)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2774)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1165)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:421)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:378)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:369)
    at org.chromium.content.browser.input.SelectPopupAdapter.getView(SelectPopupAdapter.java:56)
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46208138/why-does-android-os-8-webvew-with-html-select-tag-crash-the-app) material, but it didn't help and I couldn't find any solution for this problem. As far as I know, the app is crashed on Android 5 and 6 only. When `select` tag of HTML is pressed, it seems that Android tries to show its own `Spinner`. It uses `Resources` that causes the error somehow. I tried to create `WebView` progmatically, but it didn't help. Here is my code:

```
val webview = WebView(this)
    webview.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
    rootLayout.addView(webview)
    webview.webChromeClient = WebChromeClient()
    webview.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    webview.loadUrl(intent.getStringExtra(URL))
```

From libraries of Google, I use following:

```
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-beta01'
```

My question is how to avoid this error? Maybe we can create custom `WebView`?

Comment: I also experience this crash. This is the only thread in the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I reduced `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2` and it worked. But, sometimes downgrading `appcompat` version does not help. You should look into other libraries, that can cause the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem independent of the version of appcompat (I tried 1.0.2 and 1.2.0), and it was because I was instantiating the webview using the application context instead of the activity context

Quoting the [webview documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#WebView(android.content.Context)):

> Note: WebView should always be instantiated with an Activity Context. If instantiated with an Application Context, WebView will be unable to provide several features, such as JavaScript dialogs and autofill.

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround** for this is about loading a WebView instance with app's context, so that all resources could be pre-loaded with it:

```
Application() {
  override fun onCreate() {
    WebView(this).destroy()
  }
}
```

Workaround taken from https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/77246450